# JQuery open pop up dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to open a pop up window, doing the basic thing to start with, but instead is showing me the dialog when the page loads, plus the button doesn't trigger anything.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({ autoOpen: false });
        $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
            $( "#dialog" ).open();
        });
    });
```

Here are my elements:

```
<button id="opener">open the dialog</button>
<div id="dialog" title="Dialog Title" hidden="hidden">I'm a dialog</div>
```

This are my imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/json.debug.js"></script>
```

the jquery-ui-1.11.1.js contains the Core only and not Widget, Mouse and Position.

What I am doing wrong or forgetting to import?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For opening the dialogue on click :

```
 $( "#opener" ).click(function() {
  $('#dialog').dialog('open');
 });
```

as you need to show this on  page load, write `$('#dialog').dialog('open');` in dom ready event as well.

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/6Lx7ypw3/)**

Comment: As well? I've written it in the ready function only. Where else?

Comment: `$('#dialog').dialog('open');` should work. place the code in dom ready after initializing dialogue.

Comment: I've changed it to that, but still doesn't unfortunately.

Comment: The dialog is simply showing when you load the page as a regular DIV

Comment: @Maged: see the demo.

Comment: Now is firing into the function, but giving me this error: "TypeError: $(...).dialog is not a function

Answer (score 0):

From the dependencies towards the top of the [dialog API](http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/) page, the following are required:

- UI Core
- Widget Factory
- Position
- Button

and the following are optional:

- Draggable (optional; for use with the draggable option)
- Resizable (optional; for use with the resizable option)
- Effects Core (optional; for use with the show and hide options)

If your jquery-ui-1.11.1.js contains the Core only, that would probably be why it isn't working for you.

Comment: Thanks! Downloading all the dependencies, the zip file contains the following .js files: jquery-ui.js and jquery-ui.min.js. Should I include both of them?